# Add a parameter in the of my URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First of all, so everyone here can undestand, I have a script to get the parameter:

```
<script>
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1] || ''
    );
}
</script>
```

This script add the parameter:

```
<script>document.write(getURLParameter('code'))</script>
```

I need to implement the script above, here:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('destiny').innerHTML = Destination.linkHtml('https://myurl.php?code=PARAMETER');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to append the result of getURLParameter('code') to your query string, you could use:

```
<script>
var parameter = getURLParameter('code');
document.getElementById('destiny').innerHTML = Destination.linkHtml('https://myurl.php?code=' + parameter );
</script>
```